# correct way getting return parameters using ctypes

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

I'm familiar with python but not with ctypes.

I've been playing around with this particular function (VCS_GetErrorInfo), and was unable to get it to work. My problem is to access the return parameters. I am working on Windows 64 Bit, but tried it under Linux too. Full documentation and in this case windows libraries can be found [here](http://www.maxonmotor.de/medias/sys_master/8811528323102/EPOS-Windows-DLL-En.zip).

The function I wanna call looks like that.

```
BOOL VCS_GetErrorInfo(DWORD ErrorCodeValue, char *pErrorInfo, WORD MaxStrSize)
```

- Parameters

  - ErrorCodeValue, DWORD, Received error code
  - MaxStrSize,  WORD, Max. length of error string
- Return parameters

  - pErrorInfo, char*, Error string
  - Return value: BOOL, Nonzero if error information found; otherwise 0

In pErrorInfo I expect "No Communication Error".

My code *(edited)*...

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

lib = wintypes.WinDLL(r"...\EposCmd64.dll")

lib.VCS_GetErrorInfo.restype = wintypes.BOOL
error_buf_size = ctypes.create_string_buffer(10) # creates a buffer
pErrorInfo = ctypes.c_char_p(ctypes.addressof(error_buf_size)) # creates a pErrorInfo from the error buffer
# And when passing in the function make sure to wrap in the ctypes.byref
result = lib.VCS_GetErrorInfo(wintypes.DWORD(0), ctypes.byref(pErrorInfo), wintypes.WORD(10))
print result
# Later to get the value of the error string
print pErrorInfo, pErrorInfo.value
```

The output

```
1
c_char_p('')
```

There is still no output.

Documentation for errors

```
0x0000 0000, No Communication Error
0x0503 0000, Toggle Error
0x0504 0000, SDO Time Out
...
```

If I try it with another error code.

```
result = lib.VCS_GetErrorInfo(wintypes.DWORD(0x05030000), ctypes.byref(pErrorInfo), wintypes.WORD(10))
print result
0
c_char_p('')
```

May I pass ErrorCodeValue wrong.

I have also tried an approach with Ubuntu:

```
import ctypes

ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("/path/to/libftd2xx.so")
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("/path/to/libEposCmd.so.5.0.0.3")

def VCS_GetErrorInfo(ErrorCodeValue, MaxStrSize):
    lib.VCS_GetErrorInfo.restype = ctypes.c_bool
    error_buf_size = ctypes.create_string_buffer(MaxStrSize)
    pErrorInfo = ctypes.c_char_p(ctypes.addressof(error_buf_size))
    result = lib.VCS_GetErrorInfo(ctypes.c_uint32(ErrorCodeValue), ctypes.byref(pErrorInfo), ctypes.c_uint16(MaxStrSize))
    if not result:
        raise RuntimeError('get error info failed = {}'.format(pErrorInfo.value))
    return pErrorInfo.value
```

Results look weird.

```
print repr(VCS_GetErrorInfo(0, 10))
'\x05'
print repr(VCS_GetErrorInfo(0, 20))
'0\xe7$\xd7j\x7f'
print repr(VCS_GetErrorInfo(0x05040000, 20))
RuntimeError: get error info failed =
print repr(VCS_GetErrorInfo(0x05040000, 30))
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DLL using `__cdecl` calling convention instead of `__stdcall`, so use `CDLL` not `WinDLL`:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> lib=CDLL('EposCmd64')
>>> buf=create_string_buffer(80)
>>> lib.VCS_GetErrorInfo(0x05030000,buf,80)
1
>>> buf.value
b'Toggle Error'
```

Note that all that extra object construction `wintypes.DWORD(0x05030000)` for example, isn't necessary.  `ctypes` figures it out if it is an integer or a pointer, but needs to be told about structures and floating point values.  It wasn't required in this case, but this is how to explicitly define the arguments and return value:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> from ctypes import wintypes
>>> lib=CDLL('EposCmd64')
>>> lib.VCS_GetErrorInfo.argtypes=[wintypes.DWORD,c_char_p,wintypes.DWORD]
>>> lib.VCS_GetErrorInfo.restype=wintypes.BOOL
>>> buf=create_string_buffer(80)
>>> lib.VCS_GetErrorInfo(0x05040000,buf,80)
1
>>> buf.value
b'SDO Protocol Timeout'
```

It also prevents calling the function incorrectly due to extra type checking and parameter matching:

```
>>> lib.VCS_GetErrorInfo(0x05040000,buf)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: this function takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

The empty string is returned for `0` (no error):

```
>>> lib.VCS_GetErrorInfo(0,buf,80)
1
>>> buf.value
b''
```

Comment: Thank you for your clarification and the minimal example! I wonder that I didn't come during all trial and error. Finally, I've almost always set the buffer too small. And the fact that the error description of 0 is empty ruins my assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I use something like this to create the error message buffer:

```
error_buf_size = ctypes.create_string_buffer(10) # creates a buffer
pErrorInfo = ctypes.c_char_p(ctypes.addressof(error_buf_size)) # creates a pErrorInfo from the error buffer

# And when passing in the function make sure to wrap in the ctypes.byref
result = lib.VCS_GetErrorInfo(wintypes.DWORD(0), ctypes.byref(pErrorInfo), wintypes.WORD(10))

# Later to get the value of the error string
if pErrorInfo.value:
    print (pErrorInfo.value)
```

Check `ctypes` doc for [byref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.byref) and [addressof](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.addressof)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks better than my approaches. But it still doesn't work. I edited my post including other error codes.